# Ability to edit Privileges pages

Tags: feature-request, edits, privileges

I was wondering if it somehow is, or would be possible in the future, to edit some of the help and [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) pages?   Specifically I notice that a few of them are missing the associated 'What badges are related?' subheadings and think this could be useful to know.

Thanks

Comment: Not relevant anymore - no more privileges pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's already possible to edit the ones on meta; there's an "edit wiki" link at the bottom of each page (there's a rep requirement involved, but I don't know what it is). I think in theory fixes to the meta pages are then periodically pushed out to the other sites, but I'm not sure if that actually happens