# Allow users with enough reputation on Meta.SO to edit the privileges page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, help-center

It was [once possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80019/ability-to-edit-privileges-pages) to edit the privileges page for everyone with more than 2k rep on Meta.SO.
I think this is a good thing:

- Moderators have other things to do.
- Wrong content can be easily fixed.
- More involvement of the community.

Downside:

- The help center should be the definitive source. (Could be solved with reviews)

**So could this please changed again?**

The actual needed reputation doesn't matter.
Some quotes to support my request:

> At the high end of this reputation spectrum there is little difference between users with high reputation and ♦ moderators. That is intentional. We don’t run this site. The community does. [Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Ehhm, yes. We run the site, and we should be able to edit the privileges page.

> Moderators are human exception handlers, there to deal with those exceptional conditions that could otherwise disrupt the community. [Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Editing the privileges pages are not an exception. Again, moderators have other things to do.

---

#### Edit

As [animuson ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209527/allow-users-with-enough-reputation-on-meta-so-to-edit-the-privileges-page#comment670731_209527) pointed out, not even mods can now edit the privilege pages "wiki", so adding [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

---

#### An other edit

Before I accept an answer ([chameleon question WHEE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)) I'd like to hear some reason for this change.

> I would just wait for their response. This could be a temporary bug or oversight that wasn't meant to be done, or they could have some specific reasons why they changed it that we're not aware of. –  [animuson ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209527/allow-users-with-enough-reputation-on-meta-so-to-edit-the-privileges-page#comment670731_209527)

Comment: If this is considered. 2k is too small. It should be around 5k- 10k IMO

Comment: It doesn't matter. As long as it is not a "mod-only" privilege. Mods are human exception handlers, editing the privileges page is not an exception.

Comment: @Tijesunimi it should be same like tag wiki in my opinion, any user can suggest, two 5K can approve and one 20K can edit without review.

Comment: I agree with @ShaWizDowArd. That would be nice

Comment: @Tijesunimi plus, it won't be rolled out to all sites automatically but rather manually by a dev after reviewing the changes, e.g. once a week. This way it's a win win situation and that's how it was before as far as I remember.

Comment: How about only >2k can suggest (or the number could change of course), and only mods can approve/reject? That way it's still "the definitive source", but there is community involvement.

Comment: I just checked. As a moderator, I am not able to edit the privilege wikis. So it appears editing was disabled completely, for whatever reason.

Comment: @animuson That is bad. So we need a SE employee to do that kind of thing?

Comment: I would just wait for their response. This could be a temporary bug or oversight that wasn't meant to be done, or they could have some specific reasons why they changed it that we're not aware of.

Comment: I removed the [tag:bug] tag...just because a particular type of user can't do something doesn't make it a bug – and you shouldn't need to use both [tag:bug] and [tag:feature-request] on the same post. It's one or the other. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some articles (like privileges) have *network wide* defaults, which can only be edited via meta SO, by SE employees. Only *site specific* help center articles can be edited by that site's moderators.

There are things (like privileges), that work the same way across *all* network pages. We don't want to end up with each site having it's own, although fixed, variant of a network wide help article, but rather fix it once for all sites, even if we have to fix it ourselves.

Comment: So is it `status-declined`?

Comment: more like [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: It was once designed in an other way.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I think you're missing a "t" somewhere...

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy assuming it was "I was once designed in an other way" - you can never know... ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes i was

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: indeed he was, probably attempting to hide his _true_ origins...

Comment: @m0sa you can see comment revisions? Cool! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd unfortunately not; I've seen _the_ original

Comment: Although the privileges page were global before too (you could only edit it on MSO) I've accepted this answer.

Comment: *[its / it's](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Its-and-It's)*

Answer (score 3):

[m0sa's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209589/166017) is correct (this behavior is by design), but since you asked for reasoning...

When we rolled out the help center, [it was requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189650/help-centers-search-feature-should-search-privileges-section-as-well) that the help center's search include the privileges pages as well. We agreed that including those pages in search made a lot of sense, but in order to make that happen, we needed to change the way they were structured on the back end. As I wrote in [my answer to the request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199224/166017):

> A side effect of this change is that privilege pages are no longer wikis editable by users here on MSO; in order to index them with the help center pages, we needed to relocate those pages to a place with different permissions. The community team is now in charge of making any updates that may be required going forward, so if you see any out-of-date or missing information from a privileges page, post to meta requesting it to be updated.

The privilege wiki pages very rarely need to be changed, so it's a manageable task for employees, and users posting meta requests to update/correct information shouldn't cause too big a wave for any metas, either.

**TL;DR:** It was more important for us to allow the privileges pages to be indexed in the help center than it was to keep them in a wiki form.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Now I'm unsure wich answer I should accept now.