# "Access to moderator tools" page in Help Center still mentions close flags

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, 10k-tools, documentation

According to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186955/was-this-flag-lost-somehow/187008?noredirect=1#comment693316_187008) by Shog, flags to close a question are no longer shown in the 10K tools. However, according to the [Moderator Tools Privilege description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), they are. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Can someone please remove the vote to close flag portions of this privilege description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed references to close flags from this page. (I did not, however, change the screenshot; even though flags for closure are no longer shown here, other types of flags – like very low quality – will result in the "close question" option appearing.)

Comment: Great, so how do you edit the page now? Is it SE team only?

Comment: It is SE staff only now, @hichris123. We had to change the permissions in order to be able to index those pages in the help center search. (More details [over here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209624/166017) if you're interested.)